# Include Li+ in force field for Molecular Dynamics

Tags: molecular-dynamics, forcefields

I want to perform some MD including Li+ ions. Specifically I am interested in Li-TFSI (aka Lithium bis(trifluoromethanesulfonyl)imide).

I tested both the ATB repository and LigParGen and neither can provide Li parameters.

The calculation [1273328](https://atb.uq.edu.au/molecule.py?molid=1273328) on ATB fails since `Atom type 'LI' not currently supported by the ATB.`
[image]
On LigParGen there is no Lithium allowed `export BOSSdir=/var/www/html/ligpargen/apps/boss-4.9;/var/www/html/ligpargen/apps/anaconda2/bin/python2.7 /var/www/html/ligpargen/apps/ligpargenCode/Converter.py -s '[Li]' -r UNK -o 0 -c 0 > /tmp/errorServer.log`

I tried two smiles as `FC(F)(F)S(=O)(=O)N([Li])S(=O)(=O)C(F)(F)F` and `[Li+][N-](S(=[O-])(=[O-])C(F)(F)F)S(=[O-])(=[O-])C(F)(F)F`

[image]
[image]

I tried also to search the Li related parameters into OPLS from [Yale](http://zarbi.chem.yale.edu/oplsaam.html) or in abmer but I couldn't find much. In amber I tried to run antechamber on my Li-TFSI.pdb input file, obtaining this:

```
Warning: Unusual element (Li) for atom (ID: 16, Name: Li).
/Users/marcodigennaro/miniconda3/envs/lammps/bin/wrapped_progs/antechamber: Fatal Error!
GAFF does not have sufficient parameters for molecules having unusual
       elements (those other than H,C,N,O,S,P and halogens).
```

**Question: Do you know any Li parametrization to add to these force fields?**

Many thanks

Comment: Just a hunch. In the error, it shows LI instead of Li. Could the Lithium atom be misspelt as `LI` in any of the input files perhaps?

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I submitted CH2O3Li as a test and receive the same error.

Comment: Also LigParGen has the same problem. There is no Lithium allowed 
```          export BOSSdir=/var/www/html/ligpargen/apps/boss-4.9;/var/www/html/ligpargen/apps/anaconda2/bin/python2.7 /var/www/html/ligpargen/apps/ligpargenCode/Converter.py -s '[Li]' -r UNK -o 0 -c 0 > /tmp/errorServer.log
```

Comment: @MarcoDiGennaro, if it is suitable, you can explore other force field repositories to see if they have the required parameters. Some popular force field repositories include CHARMM, AMBER, and OPLS. Check their documentation or literature references to see if Li+ parameters are available. for instance, here you can refer to AMBER project https://ambermd.org/AmberModels_ions.php I believe they have the thing you are looking for.

Comment: @MarcoDiGennaro Moreover, on ATB you may try to transfer force field parameters from similar atoms or ions to Li+. For example, you could consider using parameters for sodium (Na+) or potassium (K+), which have similar electronic structures and properties to Li+. However, this approach may not provide accurate results, especially for properties specific to Li+. Regards~

Comment: Thank you @JaafarMehrez, I tried your suggestions but they were not conclusive unfortunately. Do you have any other source of files for OPLS?

Comment: @MarcoDiGennaro I am sorry to hear that.. I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

So far, I could find these three sources for parameters for a LJ parametrisation of Li

|  | Ref | epsilon (kJ/mol) | sigma (Ang) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [CL&P for ionic liquids](https://github.com/paduagroup/clandp/blob/master/il.ff) | 0.07648 | 2.126 |
| 2 | [Wu & Wick Macrom. 2010](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ma902758w) | 1.67470 | 1.400 |
| 3 | [Starovoytov J. Phys. Chem. B 2021](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jpcb.1c05744) | 0.10500 | 2.000 |

These results are different since they have been parametrized to optimize different properties and show that there is not a unique way to parametrize this element. Besides the large variability, a posteriori, I can see how transport quantity are not largely modified by the specific value.